# Job alert for jobs within 20 miles returns listings around the world

Tags: bug

My job alert is for "Jobs matching “oracle” within 20 miles of Ottawa, ON, Canada".
Results from the first email include jobs in:

Erlangen, Deutschland

Durham, NC

and numerous others.  It appears the location filter has not been applied.